# Error : Scheme missing

Tags: linux, bash, wget, tar, diskspace

please see my code below : The code above below shows that first checking the disk space available in the specific path and it must have the greater space than the allotted space and after checking the disk space it will download the file through using the `"wget"`  and after that it will extract all `tar.gz` files. As I execute my script, error's occur and it displayed : `blah.blah.blah.tar.gz: Scheme missing.`

```
#!/bin/bash

bundle=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
bundlename=$(echo "$bundle" | awk -F / '{print $11}')
diskspace=$(df -h /dev/shm | sed '1d' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
allowed=0

if [ "${diskspace}" -gt "${allowed}" ]; then
        wget -A "$bundle"

        for file in *.tar.gz; do
        gunzip -c "$file" | tar xf -
        done
        rm -vf "$file"
else
        echo "Not enough space to download the bundle"
    exit
fi
```

My question here. What does error means and can you correct my codes if you feel it's wrong ? thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the value of `$bundle` when it is being used by `wget`?

Comment: the value of `$bundle` is the URL of the files to be downloaded

Comment: I mean, what is the exact string which is being used at runtime?